# Differences in the support of inline images?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8

In different projects we are saving images to the database as blobs. When a page is called these are rendered as inline images (base64 encoded). Our customers are using different types as inline images (png/gif/jpeg).

Now it was reported that some pages do not render the inline images properly (especially IE7 / IE8) - in other cases this was reported as working also with IE8 - now I was wondering if the difference could be the type of image.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for inline images varies among browsers. In IE8, the maximum data size for a base64 image is 32kb.

IE9+ does not have the size limitation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx

EDIT: Technically, IE9+ DOES have a size limit, but it's 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

The types of images do not play a role at all. The only problem is the support of base64 encoded images on different browsers, I had the same problem a year ago tried every solution for IE8 and 7, only came up with a solution of NOT including inline images, but rather creating images dynamically using `PHP` as that was what my project required.

Comment: For our project this is not an option. But thanks for your reply anyway. :)